# How to add text to a bitmap image programmatically? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, drawing

I'm using a Kinect sensor to show a video feed on an image by setting the video feed as bitmap source like shown below. But my question is how would I add text to the image/bitmap for example a score counter, I added a picture below to show what I'm trying to achieve.

```
void myKinect_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {

                if (colorFrame == null) return;
                byte[] colorData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];
                colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorData);

                 KinectVideo.Source = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96,
                    PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel);

            }
        }
```

[image: Kinect video feed with overlay text]

Comment: why add to the bitmap image itself?  Add a layer on top of it with a transparent background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw text over a bitmap image? WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888687/how-to-draw-text-over-a-bitmap-image-wpf)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve this using `DrawingVisual` and `DrawingImage` classes :

[image]

```
var random = new Random();
var pixels = new byte[256 * 256 * 4];
random.NextBytes(pixels);
BitmapSource bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(256, 256, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null, pixels, 256 * 4);
var visual = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    drawingContext.DrawImage(bitmapSource, new Rect(0, 0, 256, 256));
    drawingContext.DrawText(
        new FormattedText("Hi!", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface("Segoe UI"), 32, Brushes.Black), new Point(0, 0));
}
var image = new DrawingImage(visual.Drawing);
Image1.Source = image;
```

Unfortunately you will have to create a new `BitmapSource` as there's currently no way I know of writing text directly to it.

Alternatively you could use `WriteableBitmapEx` : https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

- create a WriteableBitmap from your frame using `BitmapFactory` (1)
- create another WriteableBitmap and draw text on it using the above method (2)
- blit the text bitmap (2) over your frame (1)

Same result but different approach, not sure whether approach 2 is better as it's cumbersome.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I have one more problem to solve.How do I place an image over the bitmap, for example an image file of a car? Would I have to draw this to the screen or what method would be best?

Comment: If your image is a file (PNG etc ...) create a `BitmapImage` (which is a `BitmapSource` btw) and draw it inside the context above. If your image is an `Image` control then its `Source` property is an `ImageSource` that you can probably cast to `BitmapImage`. Take a look at the hierarchy of classes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource(v=vs.110).aspx. Update your question with an example of the problem otherwise.

Comment: I posted a new question relating to this,could you take a look at your if you have time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915705/how-to-draw-overlay-an-image-file-to-a-bitmap-image

Comment: You finally did it ? great :D

Comment: Yes I also added to my question the implementation of the drawing code that isn't working. Could you shed some light on why its not working?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to draw the text into the image itself. In your XAML just add a TextBlock control at a higher Z order.

Comment: I understand now, place the textblock on the image and set visibility when needed.How would I add another image to the image source, should this be drawn to the feed or placed on the xaml?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean exactly. Can you elaborate on what you want to do?